# Detect ng-repeat elements length change in directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have angular-sly-carousel directive and some data on it. My data is adding when user scroll down , so after scrolling i need to reload sly carousel options.

How can I detect when ng-repeat elements length is changing ?

The piece of my source, when I should detect ng-repeat elements length change (doesn't work).

```
<li sly-horizontal-repeat-simple ng-repeat="game in value | limitTo: gamesLimit track by game.id"> 
... 
</li>


VBET5.directive('slyHorizontalRepeatSimple', function($timeout,$window) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last === true) {
            $timeout(function() {
                var cont = $(el[0]);
                var frame = $(el[0]).parent();

                // Call Sly on frame
                $(window).on("resize", function() {
                    frame.sly("reload");
                });

                // Watch , if items in ng-repeat change length then reload
                scope.$watch('value', function() {
                    frame.sly("reload"); // I need reload sly when el chang
                });


            });
        }
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put scope variable instead element.length. If Scope.variable got modified watch trigger will be fired.

```
$scope.$watch(
            function () {
                return $scope.value;
            },
            function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (!angular.equals(oldValue, newValue)) {
                  $scope.text = 'Your value now =' + $scope.value;
                    }
            },
            true);
```

Comment: Hmm , how can i use it in my case ?

Comment: Updated Code and comment.

Comment: Done . can you check this please ?

Comment: Thanks , you save my day :)